# How to Pass Login ID and passpword to Chrominum pop up validator using Selenium on clicking add button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am new to selenium hance facing basic functionality issue.I tried to fix it but i am not able to do it and looking help in this regard.

**Action performing :**

1. Opening the website
2. Clicking on the add button to add the details
3. *As soon as I am clicking on 'add' button, Chrominuim Pop up is apearing which is asking Login Id and password to authenticate.*

How to handle the Step no. 3 in this case ? I searched over internet did not find much help which respect to this usecase .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Two Factor Authentication shortly know as 2FA is a authorization mechanism where One Time Password(OTP) is generated using “Authenticator” mobile apps such as “Google Authenticator”, “Microsoft Authenticator” etc., or by SMS, e-mail to authenticate. Automating this seamlessly and consistently is a big challenge in Selenium. There are some ways to automate this process. But that will be another layer on top of our Selenium tests and not secured as well. So, you can avoid automating 2FA.

There are few options to get around 2FA checks:

1.Disable 2FA for certain Users in the test environment, so that you can use those user credentials in the automation.
2.Disable 2FA in your test environment.
3.Disable 2FA if you login from certain IPs. That way we can configure our test machine IPs to avoid this.
```

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for response! Its my application functionality. To add or modify anything ,first user has to login and hence on clicking 'add' button, its asking to login via Chrominuim pop up validator.

Comment: If my answer usefull to you please accept my answer by click green tick

Answer (score 0):

If pop is similar to as seen in this website
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

then here is solution for the same

```
String username = "admin";
String password = "admin";
String url = "the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth";
url = "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + url;
driver.get(url);
```

Comment: After Website launch, and click operation login details needs to be passed. Hence this is not what i am looking for. Thank you